# Credential saving error when connecting to service on docker

Tags: docker, apple-m1, nvidia-docker

I am on a silicon chip Macbook Pro running macOS Monterey version 12.0.1 and the following error occurs on attempting to connect to the NGC service using `sudo docker login ncvr.io`.

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Post "http://ipc/registry/credstore-updated": dial unix /var/root/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/backend.sock: connect: no such file or directory`
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You will need to have docker running. Try opening Docker Desktop and attempt your login again.

Answer (score 31):

i had the same issue and could resolve it by deleting the `~/.docker/config.json` file. originally it contained only one entry being "credStore=desktop". after deletion, and trying to login again, it changed to "osxkeychain".

source: https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/213

Comment: Surprisingly it worked also for me, but I don't understand why :(

Comment: Also worked for me in macOS.

Comment: Simply opening Docker Desktop, a newly upgraded version on my system I think, fixed the issue for me. My ~/.docker/config.json file had set `"credsStore": "desktop"` for what it's worth.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me on Docker version 4.13.0  macOs

Comment: This can be used when you are not using docker desktop anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I find that running the following (assuming you are already on the command line) helps

```
mv ~/.docker/config.json ~/.docker/config.json.old
cat ~/.docker/config.json.old | sed /credsStore/d > ~/.docker/config.json
rm ~/.docker/config.json.old
```

or, all in one go as part of my run script

```
mv ~/.docker/config.json ~/.docker/config.json.old; cat ~/.docker/config.json.old | sed /credsStore/d > ~/.docker/config.json; rm ~/.docker/config.json.old
```